# How to implement and use the sub-modes feature from System.Console.CmdArgs

Tags: haskell, command-line

I would like to create a kind of swiss-knife tool for a specific domain, and a "cabal" or "darcs" command-line interface looks perfect.

Using the on-line tutorials I could implement a simple "hello, world" program. Then I implemented a more sophisticated solution with modes and all when well.

But now, I would like to explore the "sub-modes" to have a good understanding of all the possibilities, and I'm stuck. I could not find any tutorial, example or detailed description of the feature.

How to implement and use the submodes feature?

I want to clarify that I understand modes, but it's really the submodes that are not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmdargs` [tutorial](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/cmdargs/cmdargs.htm) has examples for sub-modes.  The documentation for the [`modes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html#v%3amodes) function is also clear.

In fact, a Google search for "cmdargs modes" reveals [quite](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/haskell-using-cmdargs-single-and-multi-mode/) [a few more](http://www.michaelxavier.net/posts/2011-02-27-Building-a-Haskell-CLI-Utility-with-CmdArgs.html) [tutorials](http://blog.clement.delafargue.name/posts/2013-03-05-cli-parsing-with-cmdargsexplicit.html) covering exactly this.

Comment: The tutorial links where well hidden in links and the first one was not very relevant, the two others much more but unfortunately I didn't notice them at the first reading.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, [CmdArgs: Easy Command Line Processing](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/cmdargs/cmdargs.htm), linked from the project home page, is the place to start. It includes some examples; if they are unclear I'd fetch their full code and play around with it.

The also-mentioned search results include [Haskell: Using CmdArgs (Single and Multi-Mode)](http://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/haskell-using-cmdargs-single-and-multi-mode/) and [Building a Haskell CLI Utility with CmdArgs](http://www.michaelxavier.net/posts/2011-02-27-Building-a-Haskell-CLI-Utility-with-CmdArgs.html).

[hledger's use of cmdargs](https://github.com/simonmichael/hledger/blob/master/hledger/Hledger/Cli/Options.hs#L30) is another example. It's a bit more complicated, allowing modes to be imported and reused across multiple executables.